# Restricted sum version of multinomial theorem

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, multinomial-coefficients

The multinomial theorem states that
$$
\sum_{\substack{n_1 \geq 0, \ldots, n_k \geq 0\\ n_1 + \cdots + n_k = n}} {n \choose n_1, \ldots, n_k} \, p_1^{n_1} \cdots p_k^{n_k} 
= (p_1 + \cdots + p_k)^n \,.
$$

Is there a simple closed-form expression for the closely-related sum
$$
\sum_{\substack{m > n_1 \geq 0, \ldots, m > n_k \ge 0\\ n_1 + \cdots + n_k = n}} {n \choose n_1, \ldots, n_k} \, p_1^{n_1} \cdots p_k^{n_k} \,,
$$
where no summed-over integer is allowed to exceed some maximum value, in this case $m$?

Evaluating this sum would be useful in calculating the probability that a given event $i \in \{1, \ldots, k\}$ is the mode of a sample of a multinomial distribution.

Comment: number of integer partitions where all parts smaller than $m$. OEIS: https://oeis.org/A026820 https://doiserbia.nb.rs/Article.aspx?ID=1452-86300802222R