# A seemingly obvious inequality: the restricted multinomial probability $\geq$ the product of binomial probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inequality, bernoulli-distribution

Given a normalized real vector $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (its elements sum up to $1$, i.e., $||\theta||_1 = 1$),  an integer vector $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$ and an integer $S \geq \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i$, prove or disprove that

$$S! \sum\limits_{\sum y_i = S; x_i \leq y_i} \prod \limits_{i=1}^n\frac{\theta_i^{y_i}}{y_i !} \geq \prod\limits_{i=1}^n \sum\limits_{t=x_i}^{S - \sum\limits_{j=1}^{i-1}x_j}\binom{S - \sum\limits_{j=1}^{i-1}x_j}{t}\theta_i^t(1-\theta_i)^{S - \sum\limits_{j=1}^{i-1}x_j - t}$$

In other words, we need to estimate the probability of distributing $S$ balls in $n$ bins such that the $i$-th bin contains at least $x_i$ balls (LHS), via a product of binomial probabilities (RHS).

For example, $\theta = [0.3, 0.7]$, $x = [0, 1]$, $S = 3$.

$LHS = 1-(0.3)^3 = 0.973$.

$RHS = 1 \times (0.7)^0 (0.3)^3 =0.973$.

$x_1 = 0, S - \sum\limits_{j=1}^{0}x_j = 3$;

$x_2 = 1, S - \sum\limits_{j=1}^{1}x_j = 3$;

$LHS \geq RHS$.

=======================

Numerical experiments suggest that the inequality is True. The RHS can be directly calculated, and the LHS can be calculated in $O(nSlogS)$ time via divide-and-conquer+FFT. However, I have no idea how to prove or disprove it.

Related MSE question: [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4795502/restricted-sum-version-of-multinomial-theorem).

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to require the $x_i$ to be non-negative?

Comment: I think the $\theta$ on the left should be $\theta_i$?

Comment: Thanks, ambiguities are fixed!

Comment: Should the inequality be the other way around? Letting $N_i$ be the number of observations of $i$ in $S$ draws from a law $\theta$ on $[1:n],$ you're asking if $$ P(\forall i, N_i \ge x_i) \ge \prod P(N_i \ge x_i|M_i = y_i),$$ where $M_i = \sum_{j < i} N_j, y_i = \sum_{j < i} x_j$. But, since the marginal law of $N_i|N_1^{i-1}$ depends only on $M_i$, the LHS decomposes to $\prod P(N_i \ge x_i|M_i \ge y_i),$ and (at least if $x_i \ge 1$) this is termwise smaller than the RHS since $\{M_i\ge y_i\}= \{M_i\ge S-x_i+1\} \cup \{ M_i \in [y_i: S-x_i]\}$, and under the first event $N_i \le x_i - 1$.